# Задать фон блоку картинкой, путь к которой указан в дочернем блоке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Высота и ширина блока задаются по такому принципу нормально но вот почему фон не получается вставить, не понимаю.

```js
   var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
  height = width / 3,
  bg = $('.views-field-nothing').find('.views').html();
bg = "url('" +bg+ "')";
//$(".views-field-nothing").attr("<img src=", bg);

$(".views-field-nothing").css('background', bg);

$(".views-field-nothing").css('height', height);
$(".views-field-nothing").css('width', width);
```

```css
.views-field-nothing {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg</div>
</div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png</div>
</div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif</div>
</div>
```

Comment: посмотрите значение `bg`

Comment: так смотрел, там абсолютный путь на картинку, пробовал еще так: bg= url('" + bg + "')", но тоже не сработало.

Comment: подскажите где ошибаюсь?

Comment: я события не увидел по какому будет происходить замена фона ? Оно есть ?

Comment: не будет события. страница загрузилась, скрипт работает. Смотрите исправил, фон теперь встает но везде одинаковый как написать чтобы  родителям присваивался фон путь на который указан у детей

Comment: даже при загрузке страницы есть событие к примеру window.load. Jquery посторем насколько я помню на событиях и попробуйте backgroung-image вместо background и потом если я правильно понимаю для свойства background-image нужно использовать url должно быть такого вида background:url(http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg) а вы задетете так background:http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg так только цвет определяется.

Comment: Вот так попробуйте $(".views-field-nothing").css('backgroundImage', 'url(bg)');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что элементов три, и надо каждый обойти индивидуально, либо циклом `for()`, либо методами `each(), map()`. Каждому элементу выбрать url и присвоить, а у вас солянка, весь процесс происходит один раз.

Плохой подход ставить урл картинки в диве, проще сделать это в data-элементе. Например так, оттуда извлекать очень просто:

```
<div class="views-field-nothing"
    data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></div>
```

```js
$(function(){
  
 var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
 height = width / 3,
 bg = $('.views-field-nothing').find('.views').text();

 $('.views-field-nothing .views').each(function(index, el) {
  var bg = "url('" + $(el).text() + "')";
  console.log(bg);
  $(el).parent().css('backgroundImage', bg);
  $(el).parent().css('height', height);
  $(el).parent().css('width', width);
 });
  
});
```

```css
.views-field-nothing {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg</div>
</div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png</div>
</div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
  <div class="views">http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif</div>
</div>
```